# Check for entry and insert if not duplicate PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this script which looks at inputs $area1 and $area2 and checks them against my database, if they are not then it inputs them. This is what I have written but I'm new to PHP and it's not working, not only that I believe there is a better way to do this but I'm unsure of a more efficient solution.

```
$query1 = "SELECT location_name FROM locations WHERE (location_name = '$area1')";
$connect->query($query1);
if ($partner_result = $connect->query($query1)) {
    $partner_row = $partner_result->fetch_row();
    if(!empty($partner_row)) {
        $partners = $partner_row;
        print_r($partners);
    } else {
        $insert_location = "INSERT INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area1."')"
        $connect->query($insert_location);
        echo "Location added<br>";
        $partners = false;
    }
    $partner_result->close();
} else {
    $get_partners = false;
}
$query3 = "SELECT location_name FROM locations WHERE (location_name = '$area2')";
$connect->query($query2);
if ($partner_result = $connect->query($query2)) {
    $partner_row = $partner_result->fetch_row();
    if(!empty($partner_row)) {
        $partners = $partner_row;
        print_r($partners);
    } else {
        $insert_location = "INSERT INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area2."')"
        $connect->query($insert_location);
        echo "Location added<br>";
        $partners = false;
    }
    $partner_result->close();
} else {
    $get_partners = false;
}
```

Comment: What (or which query) doesn't work? Are there any errors?

Comment: Something happened when you pasted the code and it's shoved off to the right so far you can barely read it. Is this `mysqli` or PDO or something else?

Comment: For a start you've got syntax errors. Your insert lines don't have a semi-colon.

Comment: why are you calling `->query()` twice for the top-level `if()` calls? All that does is waste a bunch of cpu time. and if you want to check for dupes, you're going about it wrong - you're building race-condition code. There's `insert ...  on duplicate key update` for a reason.

Comment: Looking at your SQL, it would assume that `location_id` is your primary key and potentially using an autoincrement? If so, you'll need a unique index on `location_name` for the on duplicate key mentioned in comments and answers.

Comment: As a side note, the provided code is basically just wrong. Syntax errors, missing variables. If you're going to provide an example, please make sure that it's valid.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve it on the DB side **without involving too much PHP**.

Firstly, you need to have **[UNIQUE index](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)** on the "location_name" column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX location_name_index ON locations (location_name)
```

Then you can always execute [insert ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) which will **add the new locations only if they do not already exist**:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area1."')
INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area2."')
```

Additionally, from your code is not clear whether you have [secured your inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If you have - good! If you haven't you could do it like this:

```
$query1 = sprintf("INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($area1));
```